# Chrome displays black tab and the title is 'Untitled'

Tags: google-chrome, blank-screen

When I opened Google Chrome, my tab was like this
[image: THIS].

What I have tried:

I have tried going into Incognito.

I have tried other questions related like [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1187009/google-chrome-grey-background-and-sad-face-in-title-bar?rq=1).


How do I fix this? Do I have to reinstall Chrome?

Comment: For me it's worse - the ENTIRE screen goes black. I can right click and get context menus though :-)